# Bootstrap datepicker not showing even with function

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have my code on js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9n3c8726/. The datepicker needs to show up as soon as I click on the field. As you can see I already encased it in a function. Any help would be appreciated

Javascript

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input class="datepicker" placeholder="Birthday" type="text" name="date">
```

Comment: You have too many jQuery loaded and not enough datepickers. Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52622083/edit) and then create a snippet using the `[<>]` icon and post a [mcve] here with ***relevant*** JS and HTML - look in the console for errors too

Comment: datepicker lib is not included in head...just add cdn from : https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: It's important to read the `console` errors. I many cases, it says what's wrong: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
            <input class="datepicker" placeholder="Birthday" type="date" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a datepicker library. Bootstrap does not come prebundled with one. Have a look at something like https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/